# What file formats does Subversion Edge ViewVC support

Tags: svn, plugins, view

I've been looking around, and either I don't understand the answer given or i'm not asking the right question. So I figure i'll open it up. I know ViewVC is a plugin to Subversion edge. I made a email program that hooks into post-commit. At first I just attached a `href` at the end of each file added, modified, and deleted. Well most of the files don't work. If you click on Added and Deleted it says ViewVC error. If you click on a file that is not supported by viewvc diff then you get a error. So my plan is to do this..easier to just show my C# code.

```
    private string GetListElementBasedOnType(string theType, string element, int rev)
    {
        switch (theType)
        {
            case "Added":
                return string.Format(""); //TODO
            case "Deleted":
                return ""; //TODO
            case "Modified":
                return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}/viewvc/{1}/{2}?r1={3}&r2={4}&pathrev={3}&diff_format=h\">\t[View Diff]</a>", repoURL, this.RepoName, element, rev, rev - 1);
            default:
                return "";
        }

    }
```

I plan on using a regex expression to verify that I can indeed view the diff.. or even view the file. Hence my question.. what extensions/formats does viewvc support? I can't find the list on Subversion Edge, or on ViewVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [their page](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/*docroot*/help_rootview.html):

> File Contents View - Shows the contents of a file at a particular revision, with revision information at the top of the page. File revisions which are GIF, PNG, or JPEG images are displayed inline on the page. Other file types are displayed as marked up text.

It seems like everything that isn't a text file, GIF, PNG, or JPEG is not supported.

Comment: well and for reference xml is not displayed either.. yet strangely enough xaml is ???? I did a little playing around and just clicked on various elements in my repository. I figured that most programming source codes were visible and I was correct. I find it kind of strange that they wouldn't show a picture. oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but have you considered just linking to the ViewVC "revision" page?  That is my favorite ViewVC page as it lets me see the entire change and I can view diffs or see the entire file depending on what I want to do.  Example:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1485309